# SparkException after upgrade to DataBricks 14.x / Spark 3.5.0 when exporting to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, databricks

Using Spark 3.4.1/Databricks 13.3, everything works. But after upgrading to Spark 3.5.0/Databricks 14.x, I get an error.

```
my_dataframe.write.format("mongodb") \
.option("connection.uri", uri) \
.option("database", db_name) \
.option("collection", target_collection) \
.mode("overwrite") \
.save()
```

```
Caused by:
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
    Task 1 in stage 110.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure:
    Lost task 1.3 in stage 110.0 (TID 1957) (10.163.24.137 executor 0):
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder$.apply(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/ExpressionEncoder;
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB connector for spark is not standard part of Spark nor Databricks (as far as I know). You must have installed that lib on your own on cluster so you (or admin) control version of it. From stack trace I would guess that version of mongodb connector for Spark is not compatible with Spark 3.5.0. I don't know what version you use, nor if there is actually up to date version of connector compatible with Spark 3.5.0.